# DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(...) returns null on jenkins, while locally it works

Tags: java, jenkins, null, jacoco, datetimeformatter

When we run test on Jenkins with Jacoco coveradge tool, two tests that worked locally on IDE failed on Jenkins.

**Jenkins Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: formatter
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.format(LocalDateTime.java:1751)
    at valid.package.MyUtils.generateReferenceId(MyUtils.java:356)
```

**Tested Class**

```
public class MyUtils{

       private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");

//method under test
public static String generateReferenceId(StationState stationState) {
        StringBuilder referenceId = new StringBuilder();
        referenceId.append(String.format("%04d", stationState.getLocationId()));
        referenceId.append(String.format("%06d", stationState.getStoreNbr()));
        referenceId.append(String.format("%02d", stationState.getSessionId()));
        referenceId.append(LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter));  //null was found here - line 356
        return referenceId.toString();
    }
```

**Test**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({
        MyUtils.class
})
class MyUtilsTest{
@Test
        public void generateReferenceId_whenGenerate_shouldReturnNotNull() {
            //given
            //when
            String referenceId = MyUtils.generateReferenceId(stationState);
            //then
            // assertions
        }
```

Second tested method is in separate class and looks the same beside a different pattern.

```
private static final String TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT);
```

So there is no reason to put it here.
So:

1. I am wondering how DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(..) can return null
   for a private static final?
2. Do you think it's because PowerMockito
   causes problems when used with Jacoco on-the-fly instrumentation
   [PowerMockito with
   Jacoco](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo). We are issuing a lowered coverage as described in
   above link.
3. When I've inlined

   private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT);

to a generateReferenceId() method

```
referenceId.append(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyyHHmmss")));
```

test on Jenkins doesn't throw NPE anymore.

**Env details:**

Local env: Java version 1.8.0.271, Win 10 OS, country PL

Jenkins version:

```
[java]      [echo] *       Run By: jenkins on Wednesday, December 9, 2020 11:07:40 AM UTC
[java]      [echo] *          JVM: Oracle Corporation v25.231-b11
[java]      [echo] *           OS: Linux amd64 v4.14.203-156.332.amzn2.x86_64
```

Jenkins is on AWS in UK.

Comment: Can you run the test with jacoco locally?

Comment: Yes. It passes all test locally. But coverage is lowered as on Jenkins.

Comment: Could your mock tool be interfering?? Just a thought.

Comment: For sure it's not explicitly in test code. We aren't mocking DateTimeFormatter, LocalDateTime.now() or anything related with it.

Comment: When I've inline private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT); to a generateReferenceId() method test on Jenkins doesn't throw NPE anymore. <post edited>

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**

I've inline constants *DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(FORMAT)* in a tested method and it doesn't throw NullPointerException on Jenkins anymore.

```
public static String generateReferenceId(StationState stationState) {
        StringBuilder referenceId = new StringBuilder();
        referenceId.append(String.format("%04d", stationState.getLocationId()));
        referenceId.append(String.format("%06d", stationState.getStoreNbr()));
        referenceId.append(String.format("%02d", stationState.getSessionId()));
        referenceId.append(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(FORMAT)));
        return referenceId.toString();
    }
```

Maybe it's not a solution as I didn't find a root cause, but for sure it's a simple workaround.

To make sure I've made a test and first made an inline in first failing test method and it passes, while the other with constants failed. After I've inline it in second tested method is passes too.